# Identifying a component on the circuit board of a mobile phone

Tags: components, hardware

I need to identify this component which I found on a circuit board inside a mobile phone.
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a simple DC motor and, when turned on, makes the mobile phone vibrate thanks to the elevated structure (eccentric weight).

You may find more detailed information here http://www.precisionmicrodrives.com/application-notes-technical-guides/application-bulletins/ab-004-understanding-erm-characteristics-for-vibration-applications